# OS X .dictionary format information

Tags: macos, format

Who knows where can I find information about `.dictionary` format and how to manually read from it?

I know that .dictionary is a directory but I have no idea on how to handle it contents.

I would like to read it manually.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but what .dictionary format are your talking of?

Comment: I assume the `.dictionary` files located in the `/Library/Dictionaries/` folder.

Comment: The .data and .index files are probably binary plist files distilled from the xml source files. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/prepare/prepare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH3-SW11

Comment: @MartinR yep, Anne is correct

Comment: @FruityGeek Thank you. But I still have no idea how to decode contents into human readable text

Comment: @FruityGeek You're awesome

Comment: [`reverse_data.py`](https://github.com/fab-jul/parse_dictionaries/blob/main/reverse_data.py) from [`parse_dictionaries`](https://github.com/fab-jul/parse_dictionaries) can be used to extract individual entries from dictionaries. There is an accompanying blog posting describing the [technical background](https://fmentzer.github.io/posts/2020/dictionary/). [`apple-dictionary`](https://github.com/JadedTuna/apple-dictionary) can be used to extract an entire dictionary. For [usage examples](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449571/10074) see my answer to a very similar question.